# Extract row from a data frame and make it a new data frame and change its index as like column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame df like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0,2,5,3], [3,1,4,2], [1,3,5,2], [5,1,3,4], [4,2,5,1], [2,3,5,1]]))
df
```

Now, I need first row of data frame and make it another data frame

```
df=df.iloc[0]
```

df

like

```
0    0
2    2
5    5
3    3
```

but my output come like

```
0    0
1    2
2    5
3    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rename` for convert indices:

```
s = df.iloc[0].rename(df.iloc[0])
print (s)
0    0
2    2
5    5
3    3
Name: 0, dtype: int32
```

If need one column `DataFrame`:

```
df1=df.iloc[0].rename(df.iloc[0]).to_frame('col')
print (df1)
   col
0    0
2    2
5    5
3    3
```

Or:

```
s = pd.Series(df.iloc[0].to_numpy(), index=df.iloc[0])
#for oldier pandas versions
#s = pd.Series(df.iloc[0].values, index=df.iloc[0])
print (s)
0    0
2    2
5    5
3    3
dtype: int32
```

Comment: @Pranab - answer was edited.